# Necessary and sufficient conditions for one sided derivatives to exist

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. We denote the left and right hand derivative respectively by $Lf'$ and $Rf'$. If the two exist and match at a point, we say that $f$ is differentiable at that point. I have the following queries:

$(1)$ What are the necessary conditions for $Lf'(x_0)$ and $Rf'(x_0)$ to exist? My guess is that we need continuity. What else?

$(2)$ What are the sufficient conditions for $Lf'(x_0)$ and $Rf'(x_0)$ to exist? Continuity is not enough (for example, $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ at $x=0$). What else do we need?

In case of any confusion, I'm defining the one sided derivatives:

$$Lf'(x_0)=\lim\limits_{x \to x_0-} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0},\,\, Rf'(x_0)=\lim\limits_{x \to x_0+} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

Comment: Have you considered the questions: 'what are necessary conditions for $f'(x_0)$ to exist?,'what are sufficient conditions for $f'(x_0)$ to exist?'

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy That should be all the conditions here plus $Lf'(x_0)=Rf'(x_0)$.

Comment: The function must indeed be continuous at $x_0$ for both $Lf'$ and $Rf'$ to exist. If not, $f(x)-f(x_0)$ will not converge to $0$ at least on one side. As far as I know, there is no other necessary and sufficient condition apart from : $Rf'$ and $Lf'$ both exist.